# Rule based sorting for each subset in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sorting rule for a column of a dataframe I am working on. The rule is the position of two consecutive rows will change 50% of the time if the ratio of the values of two consecutive values of a specific column is within a defined range. Here is the coded

```
def randomized_sort(df):
"""
:param df: dataframe
:return: sorted dataframe based on the condition
"""
length = len(df) if len(df) % 2 == 0 else len(df) - 1
for i in range(0, length, 2):
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        if (0.7 < (df.iloc[i, :].weight) / (df.iloc[i + 1, :].weight) < 1.3):
            a, b = df.iloc[i, :].copy(), df.iloc[i + 1, :].copy()
            df.iloc[i, :], df.iloc[i + 1, :] = b, a
return df
```

However, I have a new dataframe in which I have to perform this operation in each subset /group. Please see below the data. The above operation needs to be done for each subset grouped by order column.

[image: dataframe]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it is not clear, what you mean by subset/group.

Assuming, you want to treat each unique value in the `order` column as its own subset/group, you could simply filter your DataFrame for a given `order` value and process it with your method.
Afterwards, you can then concatenate all your individual DataFrames back together.

Example with dummy DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
number_of_rows = 20
df["order"]=[random.randint(0,3) for x in range(number_of_rows)]
df["weight"]=[random.randint(300,900) for x in range(number_of_rows)]
df.sort_values(by="order",inplace=True)
```

| index | order | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 629 |
| 1 | 0 | 842 |
| 3 | 0 | 326 |
| 5 | 0 | 533 |
| 6 | 0 | 621 |
| 17 | 1 | 772 |
| 11 | 1 | 333 |
| 10 | 1 | 399 |
| 18 | 1 | 369 |
| 19 | 1 | 380 |
| 7 | 1 | 414 |
| 4 | 1 | 800 |
| 2 | 1 | 640 |
| 8 | 1 | 670 |
| 14 | 2 | 411 |
| 15 | 2 | 862 |
| 16 | 2 | 888 |
| 9 | 2 | 526 |
| 12 | 3 | 345 |
| 13 | 3 | 430 |

Now filter the DataFrame for subset with `order` value of 1:

```
df[df["order"]==1]
```

| index | order | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 1 | 772 |
| 11 | 1 | 333 |
| 10 | 1 | 399 |
| 18 | 1 | 369 |
| 19 | 1 | 380 |
| 7 | 1 | 414 |
| 4 | 1 | 800 |
| 2 | 1 | 640 |
| 8 | 1 | 670 |

And then run your method with this  subset DataFrame:

```
subset_df = df[df["order"]==1].copy()
sorted_df = randomized_sort(subset_df)
sorted_df
```

| index | order | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 1 | 772 |
| 11 | 1 | 333 |
| 10 | 1 | 369 |
| 18 | 1 | 399 |
| 19 | 1 | 380 |
| 7 | 1 | 414 |
| 4 | 1 | 800 |
| 2 | 1 | 640 |
| 8 | 1 | 670 |

Now, do this in a loop for every subset:

```
ordered_subsets = sorted(df.order.unique())

overall_sorted_df=pd.DataFrame()

for order_value in ordered_subsets:
  subset_df = df[df["order"]==order_value].copy()
  sorted_df = randomized_sort(subset_df)
  overall_sorted_df = pd.concat([overall_sorted_df,sorted_df])

overall_sorted_df
```

| index | order | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 842 |
| 1 | 0 | 629 |
| 3 | 0 | 326 |
| 5 | 0 | 533 |
| 6 | 0 | 621 |
| 17 | 1 | 772 |
| 11 | 1 | 333 |
| 10 | 1 | 399 |
| 18 | 1 | 369 |
| 19 | 1 | 414 |
| 7 | 1 | 380 |
| 4 | 1 | 640 |
| 2 | 1 | 800 |
| 8 | 1 | 670 |
| 14 | 2 | 411 |
| 15 | 2 | 862 |
| 16 | 2 | 888 |
| 9 | 2 | 526 |
| 12 | 3 | 345 |
| 13 | 3 | 430 |

Hope that helps!